# Child attribute not recognized when created by backref= in parent relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have couple of sqlalchemy models with the following schemas

```
class CM(Base):
    __tablename__ = "cm"

    id = Column("id", Integer(), primary_key=True)
    status = Column("status", String(32), nullable=False)
    hostname = Column("hostname", String(128), nullable=False)
    faults = relationship(
        "Fault", backref="cm", lazy="selectin", cascade="all, delete-orphan"
    )

class Fault(Base):
    __tablename__ = "fault"

    id = Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True)
    cm_id = Column(
        Integer,
        ForeignKey("cm.id", ondelete="CASCADE"),
        index=True,
        nullable=False,
    )
    component = Column("component", Text(255))
```

When I `select` the parent table(i.e **one** side of one-to-many relation) which in my case is `CM` everything works fine

```
select(CM).filter(CM.faults.any(component="fake"))
<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select object at 0x105187910>
```

If I try selecting the other way around it seems to fail

```
select(Fault).filter(Fault.cm.has(hostname="fake"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Fault' has no attribute 'cm'
```

It turns out that if the related column `cm` is loaded in some way then the above `select` starts to work, so if I do something like this

```
session.query(Fault).filter(Fault.cm.has(hostname="fake"))
<sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query object at 0x10da57fd0>
select(Fault).filter(Fault.cm.has(hostname="fake"))
<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select object at 0x10da669d0>
```

Or even this

```
select(CM).filter(CM.faults.any(component="fake"))
<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select object at 0x1077a39d0>
select(Fault).filter(Fault.cm.has(hostname="fake"))
<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select object at 0x1077bb510>
```

My guess is `select` is not able to load the related field on many side of the relationship, but I am not sure how do I fix.

In fact I also tried renaming the backref column to something else from `cm` so that it doesn't conflict with table name and even that did not work.

I can use the sqlalchemy 1.x style `query` API using `session.query` to workaround this but since `query` API will be removed from 2.x is there a way to make it work with `select`.

Comment: You're using `selectin` lazy loading now, which seems not to be loading the `cm` attribute now. You can read about loading techniques here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_relationships.html#relationship-loading-techniques

I think any strategy should work, but I'm wondering if theres possibly an issue with the crafted sql statement due to the fact that your backref column name is the same as the table name (both `cm`). You may want to turn on echo in your engine to view the queries and ensure that they are what you would expect for this loading.

Comment: Yes any loading strategy would work and I actually tried with different strategies as well. Wrt `echo=True`, it is actually turned on however that will show sql on `session.execute` and I am getting the error as soon I craft the select statement. In fact I also tried renaming the backref column and even that did not work.

Comment: Possibly replace the `backref` in CM with two `back_populates` to ensure python interpreter knows `Fault` has a `cm` field? https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many

Comment: GitHub discussion [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/7313). TL;DR - Call `configure_mappers()` or use `back_populates=` instead of `backref=`.

Comment: Also, as noted [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_20.html#migration-orm-usage): "there is no plan to actually remove the `Session.query()` API itself [from version 2.0], as it is now implemented by using the new API internally it will remain as a legacy API, and both APIs can be used freely".

Answer (score 1):

Specifying `relationship("Fault", backref="cm", …)` in the `CM` class will "automagically" create a `cm` attribute in the `Fault` class, but that attribute does not get created immediately on declaring (or importing) the models. If the first thing we do is

```py
q = select(Fault).filter(Fault.cm.has(hostname="fake"))
```

then we get the error

> AttributeError: type object 'Fault' has no attribute 'cm'

The magic in the child class normally happens the first time that the parent class is instantiated

```py
dummy_cm = CM(status="foo", hostname="bar")

q = select(Fault).filter(Fault.cm.has(hostname="fake"))
# no error
```

Another option is to call `configure_mappers()` before doing any real work

```py
configure_mappers()

q = select(Fault).filter(Fault.cm.has(hostname="fake"))
# no error
```

However, [backref is now considered legacy](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/commit/6e8c390c1b937d842893646fb59785eaa48b243b) so the preferred approach is to use `back_populates=` instead of `backref=` and explicitly declare the attributes in both classes:

```py
class CM(Base):
    # …
    faults = relationship("Fault", back_populates="cm", …)


class Fault(Base):
    # …
    cm = relationship("CM", back_populates="faults", …)
```

Comment: Thanks Gord Thompson, using `back_populates` instead of `backref` seems to do the trick.